# Vue in vs2019, and chrome, when i make code changes they don't showup when I run the app

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome, npm

so I've got a bunch of links at the top of my vue app

```
 <v-app>
            <v-app-bar app>
                <router-link class="pa-2" to="/">Home</router-link> |
                <!--<router-link class="pa-2" to="/about">About</router-link> |-->
                <router-link class="pa-2" to="/StudentPasswordSet">StudentPasswordSet</router-link> |
                <router-link class="pa-2" pr-2 to="/StudentPortalData">StudentPortalData</router-link> |
                <router-link class="pa-2" pr-2 to="/GetStudentInfo">GetStudentInfo</router-link> |
                <router-link class="pa-2" pr-2 to="/GetStudentInfoSingleFile">GetStudentInfoSingleFile</router-link> |
                <router-link class="pa-2" pr-2 to="#" v-on:click.prevent="login" v-if="!user">StudentPortalData</router-link> |
                <router-link class="pa-2" pr-2 v-if="user" to="/StudentPortalDlSched">Stud DL Sched</router-link> |
                <router-link class="pa-2" pr-2 to="/StudentPortalDlSchedTS">Stud DL Sched TS</router-link> |

                <a href="https://dev-236765.okta.com/home/office365/0oa164ehoco8kRUHL4x7/30781" target="_blank"> 0365 with Vue Karl</a> |
                <a href="https://portal.office.com" target="_blank"> 0365 with Vue Karl2</a> |

                <!--<a href="https://dev-236765.okta.com/home/google/0oa3mblbqpfFuNHjx357/54" target="_blank"> Calendar with Vue</a> |

                <a href="https://dev-236765.okta.com/home/google/0oa3mblbqpfFuNHjx357/50" target="_blank"> GMail with Vue</a> |

                <a href="https://accounts.google.com/Logout?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fclassroom.google.com" target="_blank"> Google Classroom with Vue</a> |-->
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn @click.prevent="login" color="primary" class="pa-2" v-if="!user">Login with Okta</v-btn>
                <v-btn @click.prevent="logout" color="primary" class="pa-2" v-else>Logout</v-btn>
```

I added the 2 links with "karl" in the names, stop and restart NPM run serve, successful compile, hit f5 in google...

and the new links still don't show up in my app.(no errors in console)

How do I force vue to show my code changes? in VS I could do clean, recompile, is there a NPM equivalent?

NPM run serve output

D:\TFS\EricSandBoxVueTsFromTroy\clientapp\src>npm run serve

```
> clientapp@0.1.0 serve D:\TFS\EricSandBoxVueTsFromTroy\clientapp
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
Starting type checking service...
Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit
11% building 15/16 modules 1 active ...loader\index.js??ref--13-0!D:\TFS\EricSandBoxVueTsFromTroy\clientapp\src\main.tsBrowserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 WARNING  Compiled with 5 warnings                                                                           12:19:41 PM

Module Warning (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

D:\TFS\EricSandBoxVueTsFromTroy\clientapp\src\App.vue
  66:5  warning  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
  71:5  warning  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
  78:9  warning  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
  81:9  warning  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
  85:9  warning  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
  89:9  warning  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types

✖ 6 problems (0 errors, 6 warnings)


Module Warning (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

D:\TFS\EricSandBoxVueTsFromTroy\clientapp\src\views\StudentPasswordSet.vue
   76:9   warning  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
   88:13  warning  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
   92:24  warning  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
  124:13  warning  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
  132:13  warning  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types

✖ 5 problems (0 errors, 5 warnings)


Module Warning (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

D:\TFS\EricSandBoxVueTsFromTroy\clientapp\src\views\StudentPortalData.vue
   76:9   warning  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
   84:13  warning  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
   88:24  warning  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
  113:13  warning  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types

✖ 4 problems (0 errors, 4 warnings)


Module Warning (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

D:\TFS\EricSandBoxVueTsFromTroy\clientapp\src\views\StudentPortalDlSched.vue
   68:9   warning  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
   94:13  warning  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
   98:24  warning  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
  135:13  warning  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types

✖ 4 problems (0 errors, 4 warnings)


Module Warning (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

D:\TFS\EricSandBoxVueTsFromTroy\clientapp\src\views\StudentPortalDlSchedTS.vue
  130:9  warning  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)


You may use special comments to disable some warnings.
Use // eslint-disable-next-line to ignore the next line.
Use /* eslint-disable */ to ignore all warnings in a file.
No type errors found
Version: typescript 4.0.5
Time: 3850ms

  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8082
  - Network: http://10.140.5.66:8082

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build.
```

Main.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
//import log from './logger/logger.js'; // crashes if you include this, eed to clean in out - EWB
import axios from 'axios'

import PrettyInput from 'pretty-checkbox-vue/input';
import PrettyCheck from 'pretty-checkbox-vue/check';
import PrettyRadio from 'pretty-checkbox-vue/radio';

import Vuex from 'vuex'

//js to ts conversion article: https://medium.com/js-dojo/adding-typescript-to-your-existing-vuejs-2-6-app-aaa896c2d40a

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.use(Vuex);

//Vue.use(log);
Vue.prototype.$axios = axios;

//register components to be global on all screens - EWB
Vue.component('p-input', PrettyInput);
Vue.component('p-check', PrettyCheck);
Vue.component('p-radio', PrettyRadio);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        count: 0
    },
    mutations: {
        increment(state) {
            state.count++;
        }
    }
})

new Vue({
    router,// short hand es6 notation for router: router, adding this.$router to all components - EWB
    vuetify, // same as above - EWB
    //,

    //log,
    render: h => h(App),
    store: store,// registering here makes this visible as this.$store to all components. - EWB

}).$mount('#app');
```

app.vue

```
<template>
    <div><!--id-"app"-->
        <v-app>
            <v-app-bar app>
                <router-link class="pa-2" to="/">Home</router-link> |
                <!--<router-link class="pa-2" to="/about">About</router-link> |-->
                <router-link class="pa-2" to="/StudentPasswordSet">StudentPasswordSet</router-link> |
                <router-link class="pa-2" pr-2 to="/StudentPortalData">StudentPortalData</router-link> |
                <router-link class="pa-2" pr-2 to="/GetStudentInfo">GetStudentInfo</router-link> |
                <router-link class="pa-2" pr-2 to="/GetStudentInfoSingleFile">GetStudentInfoSingleFile</router-link> |
                <router-link class="pa-2" pr-2 to="#" v-on:click.prevent="login" v-if="!user">StudentPortalData</router-link> |
                <router-link class="pa-2" pr-2 v-if="user" to="/StudentPortalDlSched">Stud DL Sched</router-link> |
                <router-link class="pa-2" pr-2 to="/StudentPortalDlSchedTS">Stud DL Sched TS</router-link> |

                <a href="https://dev-236765.okta.com/home/office365/0oa164ehoco8kRUHL4x7/30781" target="_blank"> 0365 with Vue Karl</a> |
                <a href="https://portal.office.com" target="_blank"> 0365 with Vue Karl2</a> |

                <!--<a href="https://dev-236765.okta.com/home/google/0oa3mblbqpfFuNHjx357/54" target="_blank"> Calendar with Vue</a> |

                <a href="https://dev-236765.okta.com/home/google/0oa3mblbqpfFuNHjx357/50" target="_blank"> GMail with Vue</a> |

                <a href="https://accounts.google.com/Logout?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fclassroom.google.com" target="_blank"> Google Classroom with Vue</a> |-->
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn @click.prevent="login" color="primary" class="pa-2" v-if="!user">Login with Okta</v-btn>
                <v-btn @click.prevent="logout" color="primary" class="pa-2" v-else>Logout</v-btn>


            </v-app-bar>
            <v-card outlined class="pa-10 to accent2 lighten-4 " color="#f2f2f2" v-if="user">
                <!--<v-divider></v-divider>-->
                <v-row class="ma-2" wrap>

                    <v-col cols="12" md="6" v-if="user">

                        <!--{{user}}-->
                        {{user.preferred_username}}

                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="12" md="6" v-else>

                        USER IS NOT LOGGED IN

                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
            </v-card>

            <v-main>

                <v-container fluid>
                    <router-view />
                </v-container>

            </v-main>

        </v-app>
    </div>
</template>

 <!-- to logout call this.$auth.logout() - EWB
     below sets up Okta auth in the vue app scripts
     -->
<script>

    export default {
    name: 'app',
    data () {
      return {
        user: null
      }
    },
    async created() {
    await this.refreshUser()
    },
    watch: {
    '$route': 'onRouteChange'
    },
    methods: {
        login() {
            this.$auth.loginRedirect()
        },
        async onRouteChange() {
            // every time a route is changed refresh the user details
            await this.refreshUser()
        },
        async refreshUser() {
            // get new user details and store it to user object
            this.user = await this.$auth.getUser()
        },
        async logout() {
            //await
            await this.$auth.logout();// if I await this, it just hangs - EWB

            //await this.isAuthenticated();
            await this.refreshUser();

            this.$router.push('/');

            //alert(window.location.href);
            //window.location.href = "https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=" + window.location.href.replace("http://","");//; causes redirect notice - EWB

            //force logout of googleand redirect back to here "https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue="+window.location.pathname;;


            //if (this.$route.path !== '/') this.$router.push({
            //    path: '/' 
            //}
        }
    },
}</script>


<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin: 60px;
}

#nav {
  padding: 30px;
}

#nav a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

#nav a.router-link-exact-active {
  color: #42b983;
}
    #row {
        margin: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Do you have any console output whatsoever when making changes? Even if you don’t have hot refreshes working, you should still be able to refresh the page and see the updates...can you include more code, like where you are instantiating Vue and your package.json?

Comment: I also tried deleteing the contents of the :" D:\TFS\EricSandBoxVueTsFromTroy\clientapp\node_modules\.cache" folder, but no joy.

Comment: The console output shows your server running at `localhost:8082` (the default port starts at `8080`, and increments until it finds an available port). Perhaps your browser is looking at the wrong server (one previously opened on a different project).

Comment: This is all that's in the console.

Some messages have been moved to the Issues panel.
View issues
log.js?af04:24 [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...


The issues on the issue panels are about not having set the same site on the cookie
​

Comment: That was it, Do you know how I can  get rid of the copy running on 8080? It seems to swap randomly

Comment: How are you starting the server? Through Visual Studio? There should be a `Stop` button somewhere that kills the currently running server. A quick fix might be to restart Visual Studio (assuming that the servers will be killed with the app).

Comment: I use developer command prompt on the src folder, then 'npm run serve'

If you want to add the port thing as an answer I'll mark it answered, so you get credit.

Comment: Okay, i was wrong, it's still happening, even when I'm being careful with the ports..

Comment: What shell are you using? I've heard of this problem with some types of terminals in Windows (where the server process suspends instead of exits with CTRL-C), but I don't recall which ones.

Comment: I'm using the vs developers command prompt in windows., it's handy because i can open in the IDE I'm using (vs2018). We're a .Net shop, planning to use vue as the front end in a new app.

Comment: I just created a fresh app with vue CLI, (bable, ts router, tslint), added one of the router links, and reproduced the behavior, so that is another piece of evidence pointing to the shell.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation on a good shell to use?